# visual studio/installshield set up project

Tags: installation, setup-project, installshield

i have implemented successfully custom actions in my  visual studio setup project to encrypt app.config file and also to capture user input through textboxes. However my project has 3rd party dll references which I want to merge. I have done merging using redgate smart assembly and after that when I build the setup project using the merged obfuscated assembly there is an error during installation( unable to get installer type for assembly error 1001).

Can you show me how to encrypt app.config and capture user input via custom dialog using Installshield

Answer (score 1):

InstallerClass Custom Actions ( InstallUtil ) are very fragile and should never be used.  The problem you are having is most likely that your custom action assembly has a reference to an assembly that can no longer be found on the disk since it's been merged into another assembly.

This problem would happen with InstallUtil CA's whether it's being called by a Visual Studio Setup Project or an InstallShield Basic MSI project because the problem isn't in MSI, it's in your CA.

I would reccomend you look at WiX Deployment Tools Framework (DTF).  It's a far cleaner way of implementing managed code custom actions so that the CA and all of it's dependencies appears as a single native DLL to the Windows Installer.  At runtime the native stub extracts all the files, runs your .NET code and marshals all of the MSI API calls between the two sides for you.

It's very clean and it can be used in Setup Projects, WiX, InstallShield and other MSI authoring tools because the output is a simple Win32 DLL with exported stdcall functions. ( Msi Type 1 Custom Action Spec )

Comment: thnx for mentioning WiX. I am looking at it now, and will tell whether it solved my problem or not